# Hide Scrollbars on activity start

Tags: android, scrollbar

I've come with an issue that don't know how to solve.

The problem is that I want to hide the scrollbars when the activity starts. If you look at them, when you launch the activity they're visible and then they fade out until you begin scrolling. That's ok. But I don't want them to show when the activity is launched either.

Do you know if this is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you want them to be hidden ?? or animated (fadeIn ) when you launch your activity ?

you can use this to animate ScrollViews :

```
AlphaAnimation fadeInScroll = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f,1.0f);
fadeInScroll.setDuration(1200);
fadeInScroll.setFillAfter(true);
myScrollView.startAnimation(fadeInScroll);
```

And if you want to Hide them , use :

```
myScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope it helps :)